# How to constrain templated constexpr recursive function input parameters

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, instantiation, c++17

I wanted to check input template parameters in my constexpr recursive function when I discovered that it is always failing due to evaluating entire variable range.

Example:

```
template<unsigned char t>
constexpr unsigned char test() {
  static_assert(t < 20, "param check");
  return t < 10 ? t : test<t-1>();
}

int main() {
  return test<14>();
}
```

https://godbolt.org/g/KLgxdm

Why is this happening? And is there any other way to check parameters during compile time?

Comment: What do you want test<14> to return? What do you want test<9> to return?

Comment: It should 9. But it doesn't matter, it is just an example. I think it should compile.

Comment: Because the ternary expression is a run time construct. Both branches need to be well defined which means that even if `test<t-1>()` isnt taken it still needs to exist for the compiler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the instantiation of `test<t>` always require the instantiation of `test<t-1>`, thus you have a infinite recursion without stop criterion.

You could explicitly specialize the stop criterion:

```
template<unsigned char t>
constexpr unsigned char test() {
  static_assert(t < 20, "param check");
  return t < 10 ? t : test<t-1>();
}

template<>
constexpr unsigned char test<0>() {
    return 0;
}

int main() {
  return test<14>();
}
```

Another way is to use `if constexpr`, then for the unsatisfied condition, the instantiation won't happen:

```
template<unsigned char t>
constexpr unsigned char test() {
  static_assert(t < 20, "param check");
  if constexpr ( t < 10 ) {
      return t;
  } else {
      return test<t-1>();
  }
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks for the explanation. `if constexpr` solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

As defined, the template is an infinite recursion.  Here's how:

```
template<unsigned char t>
constexpr unsigned char test() {
    static_assert(t<20, "param check");
    if constexpr (t < 10)
        return t;
    else return t - 1;
}

int main() {
  return test<14>();
}
```